# Numpy/Scipy: How to re-construct an ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on a classification problem.
I have a `ndarray` of shape `(604329, 33)` where there are 32 features and one column for label:

```
>>> n_data.shape   
(604329, 33)
```

The third column of this ndarray is a label with `0` and `1`.
I need to move this third column as the last column so that it is easier to work with when slicing is needed.

**Question:**
Is there a way to reconstruct the `ndarray` where we can move this third column as the last column?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

```
my_array = numpy.roll(my_array,-3,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it:

```
x = np.hstack((x[:,:3],x[:,4:],x[:,3:4]))
```

where `x` is your `ndarray`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [`aix`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382556/577088)'s solution, you could slice the array directly, without `hstack`.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([range(33) for _ in range(4)])
>>> indices = range(33)
>>> indices.append(indices.pop(3))
>>> a[:,indices]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,  3]])
```

It's a bit faster for small arrays:

```
>>> %timeit numpy.hstack((a[:,:3], a[:,4:], a[:, 3:4]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 us per loop
>>> %timeit indices = range(33); indices.append(indices.pop(3)); a[:,indices]
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 us per loop
```

But actually, for larger arrays, it's slower.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([range(33) for _ in range(600000)])
>>> %timeit numpy.hstack((a[:,:3], a[:,4:], a[:, 3:4]))
1 loops, best of 3: 385 ms per loop
>>> %timeit indices = range(33); indices.append(indices.pop(3)); a[:,indices]
1 loops, best of 3: 670 ms per loop
```

If you don't need to preserve the order of the columns, (i.e. if you can use `roll`) then [Mr. E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382541/577088)'s solution is fastest for large `a`:

```
>>> %timeit numpy.roll(a, -3, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop
```